# Setting readonly variables when initializing a generic-type object?

Tags: c#, generics, constructor, polymorphism, initializer

I have the following: a base class SystemBody (which has 3 readonly fields that must be set in the contructor, and never get changed in the object's lifetime), arbitrary derived classes from SystemBody, and the following generic method:

```
public T AddBody<T>(SystemBody parentBody) where T : SystemBody, new()
{
    T rtn = new T(this, ++currentID, parentBody != null ? parentBody.id : -1);
```

Which results in:

```
error CS0417: 'T': cannot provide arguments when creating an instance of a variable type
```

I am struggling to understand what I'm intended to do in this situation.

SystemBody has a constructor with the signature required, but I have no way to enforce that a constructor with that signature exists in T. (C# seems to be noticeably lacking a generic type constraint for having a constructor with any arguments)

I can't use an initializer (which does work as expected if the properties are public) because they're readonly. (An initializer would be my preferred choice)

Using `public int id {get; private set;}` has identical results to `public readonly int id;`

The only solution I can think of is to add an `Initialize` method to the base class which takes the parameters I need to set - this feels like a gross hack that doesn't feel like it conforms to the way C# code should be written.

What am I missing? Do I just have to write Initialize?

Comment: common design patterns for this problem are the [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and the [abstract factory.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)

Comment: if you restrict `T : SystemBody` do you think you could simply construct a `new SystemBody` ? because this restriction to T is already quite narrow. even if it would work, what would you do with a class that derives from `SystemBody` but has a slightly different constructor?

Comment: The way I deal with this is to define a `Dictionary<Type, Delegate>` and then stick in there all of the types that `T` can be with a `Func<X0,...,Xn, T>` to create your instance.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> `where T : new()` **The type argument must have a public parameterless
> constructor**. When used together with other constraints, the new()
> constraint must be specified last. The new() constraint can't be
> combined with the struct and unmanaged constraints.

So basically you can't.

You will need to either to change the properties to be not `readonly`:

```
new T() { SomeProperty = blah}
```

or use:

```
(T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args)
```

or use a `Func` to initialize it.